# Wix password field storage

Tags: forms, velo, password-hash

I am pretty new to WIX platform. I am currently developing a registration form where user can also enter the login password. At the moment it stores the password in a plaintext in the collection. Is there a way I can store it not in a plain text rather have  password hashing  or something? Any suggestions how can I solve this?

Any inputs are much appreciated.

Thank you :)